# Sql Oracle USING USE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use the "USING" instead of "ON" to make a query.

The problem is that in the **"Employees"** table it is called **"codigo"** and in the **"trabajan"** table it is called **"cod_emp"**.

With the USING how would you join these two tables?
According to the Oracle documentation it is possible, but I can't get it.

```
SELECT NOMBRE, FUNCION
FROM EMPLEADOS
JOIN TRABAJAN USING (CODIGO,COD_EMP);
```

The example from the oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljusing.html

The next query is similar to the one above, but it has the additional join condition that COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE is equal to CITIES.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES JOIN CITIES
    USING (COUNTRY, COUNTRY_ISO_CODE)
```

Comment: `using` requires the join columns to have the same name.  This is obviously just my opinion, but I would never use proprietary syntax like this.

Comment: afaik `USING` is just syntactical sugar for `ON` where the column names match.  If your column names don't match, use `ON`.  And even if they do match, use `ON` instead.

Comment: "According to the Oracle documentation it is possible, but I can't get it." I think you misunderstood the documentation. What the doc is saying is that if you need to join on two columns in EACH table, then you can add more columns. That second example is the same as `ON COUNTRIES.COUNTRY = CITIES.COUNTRIES AND COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE = CITIES.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE`. It is **NOT** the same as `ON COUNTRIES.COUNTRY = CITIES.COUNTRY_ISO_CODE`. You will need to use an `ON` clause (which I prefer anyway since it makes the code more portable)

Comment: From the documentation "The columns listed in the USING clause must be present in both of the two tables being joined"  *This means the columns must be the same name.*  This is similar to "natural join" and IS A REALLY BAD IDEA.  Just use standard ON syntax.

Comment: @Hogan No, natural join doesn't require column names at all and `using` is neither good nor bad. `a join b using(col1, col2)` is exactly the same as `a join b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2` with implicit `coalesce(a.col1, b.col1) as col1, ...` in the output (in case of outer join and is Oracle's adjustment)

Comment: You've also linked to the documentation for Java DB, not Oracle RDBMS. [The Oracle 19c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2080416) says much the same though: "You can use this clause only if the join columns in both tables have the same name."

Comment: "I am trying to use the USING instead of ON..." -- don't. Use `ON` and sleep well at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle 19c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2080416), not the JavaDB docs you linked to, and with emphasis added:

> When you are specifying an equijoin of columns that have the same name in both tables, the USING column clause indicates the columns to be used. **You can use this clause only if the join columns in both tables have the same name.** Within this clause, do not qualify the column name with a table name or table alias.

I you really had to use `USING` for an assignment then you could do so if you alias one of the column names in a subquery:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, FUNCION
FROM (
  SELECT CODIGO AS COD_EMP, NOMBRE FROM EMPLEADOS
)
JOIN TRABAJAN USING (COD_EMP);
```

... which doesn't seem very "comfortable". It's simpler to use `ON` to handle the name discrepancy:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, FUNCION
FROM EMPLEADOS
JOIN TRABAJAN ON CODIGO = COD_EMP;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pHXpOHNp)

It's also a good idea to qualify all of the column names with the table names or aliases so you can see where each column is coming from, and you can use table aliases to make that shorter, e.g.

```
SELECT E.NOMBRE, T.FUNCION
FROM EMPLEADOS E
JOIN TRABAJAN T ON E.CODIGO = T.COD_EMP;
```

(But you *don't* qualify common columns with `USING`, which personally I find confusing and another reason to avoid that form of join syntax.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I give you +1 hahaha.
It has become clear to me that I do not have to use "USING" but as a curiosity I am very happy to know how it would be done

Comment: It's good that they teach you `USING` in school so you know what not to use in real applications. The same goes for `NATURAL` joins. They are error prone and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Why you shouldn't use "USE" in oracle.  A quick rant.

- Can't use it when column names don't match
- Is specific to Oracle and non-portable
- Adds absolutely no value as it is purely syntax sugar.
- Since it is syntax sugar it is hard to compare to other cases where standard syntax is used.

In short, don't use natural joins ever.

Comment: And one more point: it is not Oracle specific) It works well for Postgres, MySql, SQLite, DB2, Impala, Trino

Comment: I will keep it in mind, we are learning and the teacher says that "USING" is more comfortable but I see that he is wrong hahaha

Comment: @Rayman it's very handy if you have a lot of join columns that are not null. Even with block edit it's quite boring to list `a.col_name = b.col_name ...` instead of `using(colname, ...)`, especially when the DBMS allows per-table access to joined columns (unlike in Oracle, which leads to `ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier`)

Comment: Also, the `*` wildcard will produce less columns when using `USING` since it will compress the common columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid such join definitions.
I'd rather write like below:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, FUNCION
FROM EMPLEADOS e
JOIN TRABAJAN t on e.CODIGO=t.COD_EMP;
```

This is more clear and allows for more complex join conditions. Notice also the usage of aliases, which is very important in case you have columns with the same name in two or more different tables in the select statement. I have never used that way of writing the joins or the so-called natural join and never felt I would need to.

Comment: you are missing a `ON`